# Why passing a copy of an array still alters the original array values?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

In the `main` method below,

1st : I've tried to pass `a.copy()` and `b.copy()` as arguments. Though the `solve_linear_equations` method returned a valid solution, it still tampers with the original arguments `a[][]` and `b[]`.

2nd : Then, I've tried to define two distinct variables as `tmp_a = a.copy()` and `tmp_b = b.copy()`. Using these new variables as method parameters did not help either: not always, but usually, the method tampers with the original array values `a[][]` and `b[]`.

I think, there is some kind of a tricky issue concerning Python internals that I couldn't realize. Can anybody give a hand?

```
import random


def data_create(n):
  a, x, b = [], [], []

  for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    s = random.randint(0, 2)
    x.append(random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)

    if s:
      x[i] *= -1

    for j in range(n):
      s = random.randint(0, 2)
      a[i].append(random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)

      if s:
        a[i][j] *= -1

  for i in range(n):
    b.append(0.0)

    for j in range(n):
      b[i] += a[i][j] * x[j]

  return a, x, b


def solve_linear_equations(n, a, x):
  for i in range(n - 1):
    max_row = i
    max_val = abs(a[i][i])

    for j in range(i + 1, n):
      if abs(a[j][i]) > max_val:
        max_val = abs(a[j][i])
        max_row = j

    if max_row != i:
      x[i], x[max_row] = x[max_row], x[i]
      a[i], a[max_row] = a[max_row].copy(), a[i].copy()

    x[i] /= a[i][i]

    for j in range(i + 1, n):
      a[i][j] /= a[i][i]

    a[i][i] = 1.0

    for j in range(i + 1, n):
      x[j] -= x[i] * a[j][i]

      for k in range(i + 1, n):
        a[j][k] -= a[i][k] * a[j][i]

      a[j][i] = 0.0

  x[n - 1] /= a[n - 1][n - 1]
  a[n - 1][n - 1] = 1.0

  for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
      x[j] -= x[i] * a[j][i]

      for k in range(i, n):
        a[j][k] -= a[i][k] * a[j][i]

  return x


def main():
  n = 3
  a, x, b = data_create(n)

  print("x\n", x)
  print("a\n", a)
  print("b\n", b, "\n")

  tmp_a = a.copy() # creating a copy of a[][]
  tmp_b = b.copy() # creating a copy of b[]

  print("tmp_a\n", tmp_a)
  print("tmp_b\n", tmp_b, "\n")

  print("x\n", solve_linear_equations(n, tmp_a, tmp_b))
  print("a\n", a)
  print("b\n", b, "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to run this and I get a `ZeroDivisionError`

Comment: @JacobIRR, about `ZeroDivisionError`: You're probably running the code as if it's a Python 2.x. Trying with Python 3.x does not spit out errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
  tmp_a = a.copy() # creating a copy of a[][]
  tmp_b = b.copy() # creating a copy of b[]
```

do

```
import copy
...
tmp_a = copy.deepcopy(a) # creating a deep copy of a[][]
tmp_b = copy.deepcopy(b) # creating a deep copy of b[]
```

This is because `list.copy()` only goes one level down and you are seeing unwanted changes two levels down.

Comment: I knew there was something internal... Thanks a lot.